# Silex basic Authentication -custom failure handler

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, silex

I'm building an api using Silex and I require the end-user to send credentials via basic authentication http header tag. I want to create a custom authentication failure handler

I tried this but it didn't work. The error function never gets triggered

```
$app['security.authentication.failure_handler.auth'] = function ($app) {
    return new AuthFailureHandler($app);
};

$app->register(new SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
    'security.firewalls'    => array(
        'foo'     => array('pattern' => '^/foo'), // Example of an url available as anonymous user
        'default' => array(
            'pattern' => '^.*$',
            'http'    => true,
            'users'   => function () use ($app) {
                return new UserProvider(new UserRepository($app['db']));
            },
        ),
    ),
    'security.access_rules' => array(
        // You can rename ROLE_USER as you wish
        array('^/.+$', UserRole::USER),
        array('^/foo$', ''), // This url is available as anonymous user
    ),
));
```

This is the error handler class

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface;

class AuthFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface
{
    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        return new JsonResponse(array(
            'type'    => 'error',
            'message' => 'Incorrect username or password.',
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a reminder, [Silex will reach EOL on June 2018](http://symfony.com/blog/the-end-of-silex)

Answer (score 0):

You are defining this handler for **auth** firewall (`.auth` in `$app['security.authentication.failure_handler.auth']`), but should be `default` as this is the one that requires authentication.